# Git, Github - origin/main vs origin/master

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to understand the basic concepts of git.

I've already set up and cloned a remote repository. I'm following a tutorial.
My problem is that I don't understand the difference between:

origin/main and origin/master

In the tutorial, it appears as origin/master when he types 'git status' in the terminal.
In my terminal, it appears as:

On branch main

Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'

I'd like to understand why I'm getting 'origin/main' and not 'origin/master'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`master` is the old name of Git's (and GitHub's) master branch. This term is deemed offensive, and invokes connotations of slavery. About a year ago, Git and GitHub changed the name of the default branch to the more neutral main.

Some projects have switched over, and some projects kept the old name `master`. From a technical perspective, it's just a name - you can create a project with a default branch called `main`, `master` or `spongebob-squarepants`.

Comment: Note that this only affects GitHub, GitLab and a few such remote hosting sites. This has not been changed in Git itself, and creating a new local repo with Git will still initialize it with a master branch.

Answer (score 4):

it was called master in the past. Now people use main instead. Basically the same.

Comment: this is basically all the answer OP should need.

Answer (score 1):

When you clone some existing repository, you get *all of their commits* <sup>1</sup> and *none of their branch names*.  But they still do *have* branch names.  What your Git does with those is turn them into your own *remote-tracking names*.<sup>2</sup>

A *remote-tracking name* like `origin/master` or `origin/main` is your Git's way of remembering one of *their* Git's *branch* names.<sup>3</sup>  So if they have a branch named `main`, you get a remote-tracking name `origin/main`.  If they have a branch named `master`, you get a remote-tracking `origin/master`.

Once `git clone` has finished copying their commits into your repository, and renaming their branch names to your remote-tracking names, your Git then creates one *branch* name in *your* repository.  You choose which branch name your Git should create, using the `-b` option to `git clone`:

```
git clone -b develop https://example.com/path/to/repo.git
```

for instance.

If you *don't* give a `-b` option, your Git asks their Git which name *they* recommend.  Depending on who "they" are, they may recommend either `master` or `main`.

There's one thing that's a bit peculiar here, and that is that your Git demands that this name you select match one of *their* names.  Since your names are yours, and their names are theirs, and the two need not match up,<sup>4</sup> there is no real requirement for this, but your Git still demands it anyway, probably in an attempt to reduce confusion.  So if they have *only* `main`, or *only* `master`, that's the name you'll get.

The (single) standard first name used to be `master`.  Then GitHub changed *theirs* to `main` and now there is confusion.  If you create a repository from scratch—rather than cloning it—you can choose any initial branch name you want.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, you can get fewer than all of their commits, but the usual case is that you get them all.

<sup>2</sup>Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, but they are not *branch* names: `git switch origin/main` gives you an error, for instance, and `git checkout origin/main` produces what Git calls a *detached HEAD*.  Meanwhile, the word *branch* is very badly over-used in Git.  So it makes more sense to drop the word *branch* from this phrase.  These names are just names in your repository that remember someone else's branch names; we could call them "crimson names", but they do in fact track some "remote" Git's branch names, so *remote-tracking* is sort of reasonable.

<sup>3</sup>By "your Git", I mean "your Git software, working within your repository".  "Their Git" is thus their software working within their repository.

<sup>4</sup>That is, you can call one of your branches `dwayne` while they call one of theirs `rapunzel`, and yet you can still make your commits on your `dwayne` match up with theirs on their `rapunzel`.  It's just ... confusing to do this.  Humans seem to prefer to use the same name on both sides when the goal is to have the same *commits* on both sides too.

This idea *can* go awry: if you have two different remotes, such as `bob` to connect to Bob's Git and `alice` to connect to Alice's, and both `bob` and `alice` have a branch named `cream` but one refers to a dairy product and the other to [the 1960s band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cream_(band)), you're not going to be able to have one branch in *your* repository named `cream` that somehow works for both of these.  So Git doesn't *require* it, except during this initial `git clone` step.

<sup>5</sup>This requires a reasonably up-to-date Git to do it with the `git init` command.  With older versions of Git, you do the `git init` and get started with the name `master`, then rename the branch.